# Need approach direction how to implement stream data cache in a gstreamer application

Tags: caching, gstreamer

I am a newbie in **gstreamer** world.
And I need to implement **stream data cache** in an application that is based on **gstreamer**.

(Version of gstreamer might be **1.0**)

The **stream data cache** is a cache mechanism that caches stream data and
later if the user wants to play the very same stream, the application
firstly check if the stream data is stored in cache memory/storage. And if
the stream data is found from the cache memory/storage, the application
plays it without fetching the same stream data from the source url again.

I wonder if **gstreamer** or any **plugins** provide this feature already. If not,
how am I supposed to approach to implement this cache mechanism?

(The stream data I consider is only sound/audio. Video/vision is not considered at all.)

I hope some simple advice be given to me from some of you ... ;-)

Comment: One way to do this is to use filesink to store the media file on storage. Use playbin to play the file. If file is present, give file uri otherwise give http/rtsp/rtp or any other uri to playbin.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems proper advice to me. Thank you!